# rasa core installation existing package found

Tags: python, pip, rasa-core

I am downloading rasa core and the NLU. But installing rasa core is presenting a frustrating error I do not understand.

```
pip install rasa_core
```

Results in an error

```
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, kiwisolver, matplotlib, rasa-nlu, graphviz, redis, fakeredis, decorator, networkx, fbmessenger, click, itsdangerous, flask, jsonpickle, h5py, Keras, tzlocal, apscheduler, websocket-client, slackclient, python-telegram-bot, ply, pandoc, packaging, snowballstemmer, alabaster, sphinxcontrib-websupport, babel, imagesize, sphinx, nbsphinx, monotonic, humanfriendly, coloredlogs, docopt, pykwalify, ConfigArgParse, ruamel.ordereddict, ruamel.yaml, rasa-core
```

`Found existing installation: pyparsing 1.5.6
Cannot uninstall 'pyparsing'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

I can not find any information on this error or a work around? 
My python version is 2.7 but I don't think that would make a difference.
I also don't under stand why it would want to uninstall the package to then re install it (Upgrade?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove the package manually or overwrite it:

```
pip install pyparsing --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall python package which is part of distutils, you can manually remove the folder from 'site-packages' folder. If it is Anaconda distribution, it will be in following folder. I suggest to cut the folder and paste it somewhere else for backup purpose.

```
   C:\Users\<WindowsUser>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

Following 2 items needs to be removed.

1. Folder [package version no.]
2. File - [package>.egg-info]