# Failed to upgrade plotly using pip

Tags: python, pip, plotly

I'm trying to upgrade plotly which is right now at 2.0.7 and mine is 1.3
using the following:

```
pip install plotly --upgrade
```

But I'm having this error:

```
Installing collected packages:
 Found existing installation: plotly 1.3.1
Cannot uninstall 'plotly'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: Like the error message says, `pip` cannot upgrade an install which was made by a tool which isn't `pip`. Upgrade using `distutils` or maybe use e.g. `virtualenv` to install a separate version which is independent from any system-wide install for your current project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rasa core installation existing package found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452344/rasa-core-installation-existing-package-found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50933832/7976758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

First of all I uninstall plotly using pip:

```
pip uninstall plotly
```

Then using conda:

```
conda uninstall plotly
```

After that, I installed the last version using pip:

```
pip install plotly
```

I checked Plotly version:

```
import plotly
plotly.__version__
```

which is right now `3.0.0`